# Small text in outlined text field in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to make a small quantity outlined text field in compose but the text is not visible.

This is my code:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = q,
    onValueChange = { q = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(40.dp)
        .height(40.dp)
)
```

This is the result:

[image: here's the screenshot of the text field]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why does reducing the padding or the font size not work for you?

Comment: @Leviathan I want to reduce the padding between the outline and the text.